# Is it possible to always show Assets folders as opened?

Tags: assets, image

When adding an image from an Assets field or uploading one to the Assets section *(or anywhere there is an Assets field for that matter)* if you have subfolders then it currently shows the main folder but closed so you have to click on the arrow to unfold the main folder structure.

Therefore looking for a way to have the folder structures already opened to save a click.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

From what I know this isn't possible in Craft2 (it's a known issue). P&T has probably addressed this in Craft3 with the many updates to Assets in that release.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. Only a small niggle but would be great if it worked that way. Will just have to wait patiently :-)